# My while loop is repeating over and over again

Tags: python, while-loop

it is referencing a board to a game with 9 slots and once the slots get filled up the ##while loop keeps searching for a new  spot when there aren't any empty spots and I don't know how to fix it, please help! :(

```
        computer = random.randint(0, 8)
        if board[computer] != 'X' and board[computer] != 'O':
            print computer
            board[computer] = 'O'
        else:
            while board[computer] == 'O' or 'X':
                counter = 0
                if counter > 15:
                    break
                computer = random.randint(0, 8)
                print computer
                if board[computer] != 'X' and board[computer] != 'O':
                    board[computer] = 'O'
                counter += 1
```

Answer (score 6):

Your `while` statement always returns a true value because the `or 'X'` always evaluates to `True`. First, `board[computer] == '0'` is evaluated, and if `False`, it proceeds to the right side of the `or`, which is simply the string `X`.  You do have this pattern correct elsewhere in your code, so I suspect this was just an oversight.

Instead you must include both sides of the boolean comparison:

```
while board[computer] == 'O' or board[computer] == 'X':
```

Or better, you can use `in`

```
while board[computer] in ['O','X']:
```

Or, courtesy of @icktoofay in the comments, the idiomatic:

```
while board[computer] in 'OX':
```

Your `counter` must be initialized to `0` *outside* the loop, rather than reinitialized inside.

```
 # initialize outside the loop
 counter = 0
 while board[computer] == 'O' or 'X':
    # Don't re-initialize to 0 in the loop
```

Comment: Or even `'OX'` rather than `['O','X']`.

Comment: @icktoofay Yes - my Python is rusty and I always forget about that.

Comment: Thanks for responding so fast Michael!! But after making the changes(the first one you posted) It didnt fix it, it still keeps searching for an open spot :(

Comment: There is also the problem of setting counter to zero immediately _before_ checking if it's greater than 15. It will, of course, never be greater than 15.

Comment: @user1861771 it is because your counter is set inside the loop. Move it outside.

Comment: True @BryanOakley but I only had that there as a failed attempt of stopping the while loop to break out of it, I am really new to programming and I was trying many different things :P the counter in fact, does nothing right now, so I took it out along with the if statement about the counter.

Comment: @user1861771 What do you mean the counter does nothing? It breaks out of your loop to prevent infinite looping!

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I am very new to this website, is there a way I can send like a private message to you to give you a bigger picture of my whole code? I don't want to post the entirety of my code online and then get accused of plagiarism :(  (I asked my teacher to help but he doesn't respond to emails and a 'somewhat' working version of this is due by midnight eastern time) Also, I did put the counter and everything back but now, it runs and at a random point it just fills all the spots with 'O's

Comment: @user1861771 There is no way to post code privately, except in chat rooms, but I don't think you have enough points yet to use chat.  It is better anyway to ask separate discrete questions with only the relevant code.  This question was about a loop that did not exit correctly.

Comment: Yes, but it is still not exiting properly :( Seemingly completely randomly, (this is a tic-tac-toe game) computer will generate numbers over and over again until it fills all the spots.

Comment: I tried to invite you to a chat, but it doesn't work since you don't have enough points yet. You would have to post more code here if you can.

Comment: @user1861771: Michael Berkowski solved your initial problem, and then solved another problem. If your code still isn't working because you still have more problems, I think you ought to accept his answer, figure out what your new problem is, and post a new question for it.

Comment: @abarnert I agree, but the thing is I am incredibly new to programming(first semester of my first class new) and have a teacher that isn't all that willing to answer questions. I can't really figure out my problem on my own :( I have tried, trust me. I tried to post another question with my other problem but I accidentally posted a bad question, got down rep'd and then now I have to wait to post another one hehe.

Comment: @user1861771  eventually you can ask a new one for other discrete parts of your code, but you should mark this one as accepted by clicking the checkmark beside it.